# How to install a Laravel 10 project over a Docker container already created

Tags: php, laravel, docker, php-8, laravel-10

I have **XAMPP** installed in my machine (php 7.4.3 version) and I'm working on a Laravel 6 project for my job which the `composer.json` file has `"php": "^7.2.5|^8.0"` by requirement.

I want to create a new Laravel 10 project in my machine, but this Laravel version requires php 8.1 to 8.2 to work and I don't want to update my job Laravel 6 project neither deal with changing php versions in **XAMPP** every time.

Since I'm learning Docker I would like to know how can I create a Docker container which works with one of those PHP version images and then install a new Laravel 10 project over it i.e. to create that Docker container before install Laravel 10 project, I don't even know if this is possible. Can somebody help me? how can I get it?

I'm Latin so my English is not very good looking but thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for Laravel Sail, that is your solution

Comment: Install docker first. There are a lot of docker boiler plate for laravel (PHP8+mysql,nginx,phpmyadmin) online.